# check if word belongs to locale

Tags: java, locale

I have a file where most of the words (phrases) belong to a specific language
(let's say spanish). In the same file there are some words that belong to another language (let's say english). Is there a way to find those few words using java? Could locale class could be of help? These two languages are an example. It could be russian as main language and in english the ones that I want to identify as an abnormally.

Comment: Locale has nothing to do with that. A Locale is mostly used to handle cultural differences when it comes to displaying data, e.g. dates, numbers, etc.

For your example, hard to help, not enough information about what you're actually trying to achieve. What about reading your file and counting the occurrences of each words ? Maybe the "abnormal" words will only appear once or twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locale class isn't going to be of any help in this case.  Your best bet is to put your Spanish and English dictionaries in HashSets and then check for set membership as you iterate through your file, or if the dictionaries are too large to fit in memory then put them in a database instead.